# How to center the dialog caption?

Tags: c++, dialog

I created my IDD_DIALOG in my resource file.

I am using the following code to center the DIALOG in the middle of a screen:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    RECT Rect;
    ::GetWindowRect(hwndDlg, &Rect);
    ::SetWindowPos(hwndDlg, HWND_TOPMOST, (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - ((Rect.right - Rect.left)/2)), (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - ((Rect.bottom - Rect.top)/2)), (Rect.right - Rect.left), (Rect.bottom - Rect.top), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    return TRUE;
```

My question is, how would I also center the caption (dialog title) alongside with my current code?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you can use [DS_CENTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932937.aspx) dialog style option in your resource file and windows will center the dialog for you - no need to SetWindowPos. Not sure why you'd want to center the caption - why not just let your app be consistent with other dialogs? I think it's possible, but there's no simple flag for it; you'd likely have to do some messy custom border painting and draw the caption yourself.

Comment: Yes, I made the dialog in the .rc file; never knew I could use DS_CENTER though. I was wondering if instead of the option 'Layout RTL', maybe there is something for center?

Comment: RTL is really there for languages like Hebrew and Arabic that read right to left, so they get aligned to the edge you read from. But it's really about specifying reading direction, the alignment is a side-effect; so there's no center-align option because it doesn't meet any language need. Usually you're best off just specifying the caption and letting Windows do its thing: back in Win3.1, captions were centered. Around Win95, captions then became aligned. By drawing the caption yourself, there's more of a chance it'll look inconsistent in some future version of windows.

Comment: Fair enough BrendanMcK, I thank you though for the suggestion of the dialog style option DS_CENTER, I just added that :P

Close thread moderators?

Comment: I'll reword my comment as an answer :) - I did it as a comment first really to find out if you had a compelling reason to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you really need to, it's best not to.

You'd likely need to paint a custom border/frame, which is what some apps like Office do so that they can have additional button widgets in the title bar. (Office also centers the text in its titlebar...) It's pretty complex, plus there's two different techniques depending on whether you're running on pre-XP or Vista with DWM enabled. I found an article [that summarizes some of the issues involved in the Vista/DWM case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx). And in case DWM isn't enabled, you might need to support the old technique, [handling and overriding WM_NCPAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

That's a *lot* of work just to center a titlebar!

Turns out that the justification for the titlebar has changed over time: in Win3.1, it was centered; then in the 95 era it became left-justified (or right-justified for right-to-left languages). Turns out that things have come full circle, and in Desktop mode, Windows 8 reverts to centering it again.

So perhaps simplest answer to "How to center the dialog caption?" is: upgrade to Windows 8 :-)

Comment: To add my two-cents -- this doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 (or maybe there's a new method of doing it.)

Comment: Looks like Windows changed again - seems that in Windows 10, title bar text in both both app and dialog windows is again left-justified by default. Best bet regardless is to let the OS default do its thing and not attempt to override - that way your UI will match other apps on the desktop.